# How to customize VSCode with dark colored editing area and light colored widgets?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm a newbie of the Visual Studio Code, and trying to define a custom color scheme simulating another editor I used for a long time. I hope to give light colors for editor's UI and dark colors for the contents area. Here is the repository:
https://github.com/piroor/vscode-theme-kokuban

I successfully set colors for most parts, but there are some problems. [Here is a screenshot describing the current appearance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BNTE8.png). There are two unreadable colorings:

- The top-left pane (options UI) , the middle-left pane (extension information), and the bottom pane (debug console) have dark background and dark foreground.
- The header of a hint for an unused argument (right pane) is shown with light background and light foreground.

Sadly I couldn't find out which entries correspond to these parts from the list: https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color Any hint to find entries for those parts? Or, is such coloring (dark colored contents and light colored widgets) impossible?